# 'mongoimport' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, path, jupyter-notebook, environment-variables

I'm running Windows 10 and calling `!mongoimport -d osm -c bham --file bham.json` using Python 3.85 in Jupyter Notebook, from a conda environment.

I get `'mongoimport' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` and the file is not imported.

I have added the MongoDB tools bin folder and the server bin folder to PATH:
[image]

[image]

[image]

I have also tried:

- Copying mongoimport.exe to the server bin folder.
- Putting `.\` before `mongoimport` in the command.
- Calling the file directly `!<full file path>`.
- Removing the `\` after `bin` in PATH.

This is the only MongoDB installation I have, and I can see that the database service is running, as is Compass.

It worked on this computer before I did a clean install.

Thanks!

Edit: change tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out restarting my computer did the trick. Restarting the kernel after setting the PATH variable was not it. So, it might just have been restarting the command prompt from which Jupyter Notebook was launched after setting the PATH variable that did it.